# Modify File Contents based on starting element/string

Tags: c#, biztalk, hl7

I have a HL7 File like:

```
MSH|^~\&|ABC|000|ABC|ABC|0000||ABC|000|A|00
PID|1|000|||ABC||000|A||||||||||
OBR|1|||00||00|00|||||||||||ABC|00|0|0||||A|||||00||ABC|7ABC||ABC
OBX|1|ABC|ABC|1|SGVsbG8=
OBX|2|ABC|ABC|1|XYTA
OBX|3|ABC|ABC|1|UYYA
```

I have to read only OBX segments and get the text after 5th pipe (|).

Currently I am doing this with:

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\HL7\Ministry\HSHS.txt");
 string strTest = reader.ReadToEnd();
 string OBX1 = strTest.Split('\n')[3];
 File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\OBX.txt", OBX1 + Environment.NewLine);
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
 using (reader)
 {
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       list.Add(line);
       if (line.StartsWith("OBX|") == true)
       {
          string txt = line.Split('|')[5];
          File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", txt+Environment.NewLine);
       }
       else
       {
          //string x = line + Environment.NewLine + OBX1.Distinct();
          File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\newtest.txt", line + Environment.NewLine);   
       }
```

File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\newtest.txt", OBX1.Distinct().ToList() + Environment.NewLine);

This extracts the contents of each OBX segment at element 5 (after 5 pipes) and writes out a file called test.text, in my else statement I am trying to modify the original HL7 file by deleting OBX|2 and OBX|3 to have only One OBX|1 as we expect the number of OBX segments inside the HL7 file to reach 40 or more and we don't wan't to keep those many while returning the message to its messagebox.

How do I get the first occurrence of OBX|1 without saying the line number is 4, this might change.

This is the working code:

```
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\HL7\Ministry\HSHS.txt");
     string strTest = reader.ReadToEnd();
     reader.DiscardBufferedData();
     reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
     string OBXstr = string.Empty;
     string x = null;
     string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     List<string> list = new List<string>();
     using (reader)
     {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           list.Add(line);
           if (line.StartsWith("OBX|") == true)
           {
              string txt = line.Split('|')[5];
              File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\"+fileName, txt + Environment.NewLine);
           }
           else
           {
              sb.AppendLine(line);
           }
        }
        int obx1Index = 0;
        int obx2Index = 0;
        var obx1IDR = "\r" + "OBX" + "|" + "1";
        var obx1IDN = "\n" + "OBX" + "|" + "1";
        var obx2IDR = "\r" + "OBX" + "|" + "2";
        var obx2IDN = "\n" + "OBX" + "|" + "2";
        obx1Index = strTest.IndexOf(obx1IDN);
        if (obx1Index < 1)
           obx1Index = strTest.IndexOf(obx1IDR);

        obx2Index = strTest.IndexOf(obx2IDN);
        if (obx2Index < 1)
           obx2Index = strTest.IndexOf(obx2IDR);
        if (obx1Index > 0)
        {
           OBXstr = strTest.Substring(obx1Index, obx2Index - obx1Index - 1);
           OBXstr = OBXstr.Replace(strTest.Substring(obx1Index, obx2Index - obx1Index - 1).Split('|')[5], fileName);
        }
     }
     sb.Append(OBXstr);
     x = sb.ToString();
     File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\newtest.txt", x);
     reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many flaws.

1) This assumes that OBX1 is always the 4th line, you will want to move that inside your loop and if logic.

`string OBX1 = strTest.Split('\n')[3];`

2) Yes you have the writing of the variable OBX1 occurring for every other line as it is in the else statement.

3) You are writing to multiple files, when what you are saying you want a single file/message.

You probably want something more like

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\HL7\Ministry\HSHS.txt");

 File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\OBX.txt", OBX1 + Environment.NewLine);
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
 using (reader)
 {
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       list.Add(line);
       if (line.StartsWith("OBX|1") == true)
       {
          File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", line + Environment.NewLine);
       }
       else if (line.StartsWith("OBX|") == true)
       {
          // Don't write
       }
       else
       {
          File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\vemarajs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", line + Environment.NewLine);
       }
```

Comment: I want to have two different files. The first with all text from OBX lines and the second with all elements except lines after the first OBX line.

Comment: I agree with you, that OBX|1 will not always be the 4th line. I will try to pick the value by fetching the value through its index.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [NHapi](http://nhapi.sourceforge.net/home.php), which allows You to parse HL7 messages to an object structure and then manipulate the objects. An example of parsing can be found [here](http://portal-management.blogspot.com/2009/04/hl7-parsing-using-net.html), which I assume should be usable. I have personal experience with HAPI, the original Java based version of the parser library and it really makes it easy to handle HL7 parsing.